# $E[X^2]$ computing problem. Where does it go wrong?

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables uniform on $[−1, 1]$. Find the the expected value and the variance. If the variables uniform on this set, does it mean that: $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)={1\over 2}$? If so, $E[X_i]={1\over 2}-{1\over 2}=0$. It was written that $Var({X_i})={1\over 3}$ but I don't understand why. Since $E[X]=0$, it is all about $E[X_i^2]$, but what I get is: $1^2\cdot {1\over 2}+(-1)^2\cdot {1\over 2}=1$. Why don't I arrive at $1\over 3$? What am I doing wrong? I could really use your help.

Comment: It is probably a continuous distribution on the interval $[-1,1]$ of real numbers. You have used a discrete distribution on the set $\{-1,1\}$ containing two elements.

Comment: Oh. That is not in the syllabus...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a uniform random variable means that $P(a \le x \le b) = \dfrac{1}{b-a}$. I think you're confusing this with a discrete random variable, which can only take values of $-1$ and $1$. This variable is continuous; it can take on any value between $-1$ and $1$.

With this in mind, because our mean is $0$, we have our variance as 
$$
\dfrac{1}{1 - (-1)} \int_{-1}^{1} (x-0)^2 dx = \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} x^2dx = \dfrac{1}{3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment by @doiod, please look at the Wikipedia summary for 'continuous uniform distribution'.
There it says that a continuous uniform distribution on the
interval $(a,b)$ has mean $\mu = E(X) = (a+b)/2$ and variance
$\sigma^2 = Var(X) = (b-a)^2/12.$ In your case $a = -1$
and $b = 1.$

There is also a general formula that says $Var(X) = E(X^2) - \mu^2.$
As in the answer by @Ashkay, you have $\mu = 0,$ so $Var(X) = E(X^2).$

You ought to be able to use these general results to answer your
current question, as well as similar ones in the future.

You don't say anything about the level of the course. Depending
on the level, you might try proving these three general results for yourself.